# Converting xml value &amp; to simple & using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml element has the value as **`R&amp;B`**.
See below:

```
<F4>R&amp;B</F4>
```

As per my requirement, I need to modify the value **R& amp;B** to just R&B using XSLT.
I have tried by adding **disable-output-escaping="yes"** . But it didn't worked for me.I am getting the following exception when I do that:
"The reference to entity "B" must end with the ';' delimiter".
I have used tried with the following piece of code:

```
<BenCd><xsl:value-of select="F4" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></BenCd>
```

Can anyone share thoughts on how to get it solved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? `<F4>R&B</F4>` is not valid XML. Your processor is obeying the `disable-output-escaping` directive, but you are getting an error because the result is invalid XML.

Comment: What kind of output do you want to create with XSLT, plain text or XML or HTML? For HTML and XML the right way is to escape `&` in data as `&amp;`.

Comment: I need to render the value "R& amp;B" as "R&B" in the UI end(i.e.browser). Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: You don't need a workaround. A browser will display `R&amp;B` as `R&B`.

Comment: Thanks much for your response. I am sorry.I am running a junit test and verifying the results. Let me check in the browser too.

Comment: The problem is, I am once again rewriting the xslt generated xml with few more modifications. At that time, When I parse the modified output, the R&amp;B value is converted to "RB". Looks like there is some parsing issue. Thanks JLRishe for clarifying the things.